# Can I emit light from an inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

As I understand it, inductors create a magnetic field when current flows through them, and light is an electromagnetic radiation.

So, is it possible for an inductor to generate magnetic waves of the same frequency of visible light? If no, why? If yes, has anyone attempted such an experiment?

Comment: There are no magnetic waves, there are only electromagnetic waves. In engineering this kind of object is called a "loop antenna" because it starts out with a physically closed current loop in comparison to an "open" antenna (usually just called "antenna" without additional qualifier) that does not have a physically closed loop. The "current loops" in antennas are, of course, always closed by dielectric displacement currents. While there are important engineering differences between loop antennas and open antennas the ultimate working principles are the same.

Comment: Are you focussed specifically on inductors and magnetic fields, or are you simply wondering whether an AC current at a high enough frequency will emit visible light? If the latter, the answer is "yes". Look up "free electron lasers" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser ) which can emit EM radiation ranging all the way from the microwave to the visible to the x-ray region depending on the frequency.